# How to install Virtual box guest in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I am trying to have virtual box guest in Ubuntu 18.04 but now able to succeed.

```
peter@LAPTOP-UMBBINAR:~$: sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
peter@LAPTOP-UMBBINAR:~$ Reading package lists... Done
Reading: command not found
peter@LAPTOP-UMBBINAR:~$ Building dependency tree
Building: command not found
peter@LAPTOP-UMBBINAR:~$ E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

Any idea how to run the command  ?

Comment: Hi, it is not related to repositories. I would like to establish guest account in virtual box. How to create it ?

Comment: You place the downloaded Guest Additions .iso in the Guest's Virtual CD drive. That's why it's called *Guest* additions. You do not install anything additional on the Host. You do not change any settings on the Host. You do nothing with apt on either Host nor Guest.